# Symfony2 form don't persist empty collection

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Form containing an entity with collection :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('fichiers', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new FichierType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
    ;
}
```

But, this collection contains 4 non required field :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('url', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('size', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('type', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
    ;
}
```

But if I validate the form, I don't want insert the collection because all fields are null :

**An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fichier (url, name, size, type, groupe_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 2]:**

Comment: I think it's because your entity mapping does not accept null values. Can you show us your entity mapping ?

Comment: You can also add `contraint => Valid()` to the parent form's collection type, so validation will be forced on the child. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: Have your solve this problme?

Answer (score 0):

in your Fichier Entity file, be sure to have the nullable=true annotation

like:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $foo;
```

And for YAML mapping:

```
  foo:
      type: string
      column: foo
      nullable: true
```

otherwise the generated db-scheme will default to nullable=false, so you get the Insert exception

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want nullable fields :)

All the fields isn't nullable ... but the collection can it. :)